# Trying to use two hardcode value in nested loop

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use nested loop in one loop value is running based on cursor and the other nested loop has only two condition to be looped how to achieve that

i have written proc for looping using AGE_CD value from age_val  cursor in loop but i have two different grade 12 and 14 how to put that condition also in loop instead of using union

```
cursor age_val is 
 SELECT AGE_CD,   
 FROM D_AGE
 WHERE AGE_SEQ < 8 
 ORDER BY 4;
begin
    FOR i IN age_val LOOP
      SELECT To_Char(NVL(SUM(NVL(weight, 0)), 0))
      INTO X        
from( 
   select   weight from tbl1
where grade='12' and age=i.AGE_CD;
union 
select   weight from tbl2
where grade='12' and age=i.AGE_CD;
)A
End loop;
```

Expected: the two hardcode value in grade can also be used in loop.
Actual:able to do only one hardcode value of grade in loop want to use two grade value also under nested loop

Comment: you can use `in` => `grade in ('12','13')`

Comment: "... instead of using union" - you are selecting from two different tables (tbl1 and tbl2), so ... how is that related to different *grades*? You can put any number of grades into the IN clause (OK, not truly *any number*, it is limited), but that won't change the fact that there are 2 tables involved.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a cursor or a loop for this. And you should be using `union all` rather than `union`.

`union` removes duplicates from the result, so if the same weight is returned from both tables it will only be included once in the result. AS you are calculating the sum() I assume this is not what you want. There is also no need for `NVL(weight, 0)` as aggregate functions ignore null values. You can replace the slow loop approach with a single query:

```
with ages as (
   SELECT AGE_CD,   
   FROM D_AGE
   WHERE AGE_SEQ < 8
)
select nvl(sum(weight), 0)
from (
   select weight 
   from tbl1
   where grade in ('12', '14')
   and age in (select age_cd from ages)
   UNION ALL
   select weight from tbl2
   where grade in ('12', '14')
   and age in (select age_cd from ages)
)
```

I also don't see a reason to convert a number to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is -

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN age_val LOOP
      SELECT NVL(SUM(weight), 0)
      INTO X
      FROM(SELECT weight FROM tbl1
           WHERE grade IN ('12', '14')
           AND age=i.AGE_CD
           UNION
           SELECT weight FROM tbl2
           WHERE grade IN ('12', '14')
           AND age=i.AGE_CD;
          )A
    END LOOP;
END;
```